# Power query - Power Bi - Dhis2

Tags: rest, powerquery, powerbi-datasource, dhis-2

I need help to transpose the first column in line which is added side by side with the other two columns.
How to specify it in the api other than it is parameter that I must specify that the result gives what I wanted to have?

The current result

| Data | Organization | Periode | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text1 | name org1 | month | value1 |
| text2 | name org2 | month | value2 |
| .... | ..... | ..... | ..... |

the result I want

| Oganization | Periode | text1 | text2 | text... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name org1 | month | value1 | value2 | ... |
| name org2 | month | value1 | value2 | ... |

let
Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("https://ministere-sante.mg/api/29/analytics.csv?dimension=dx:toUMbcnAgGN;O1W97xlGqBZ;arxPOcQhanb;dn8pVWUHojB;FvLKwx96Kv0;q87CgC2m7fZ;NU6LJrW5OtP;rw8lpwb5j5G;oWA1W7mmuba;qHDVI4FRFjE;qtKuAZgaMU0;rm102gbKzBZ;ACiHvHoBVtZ;IeIcIkISFW4;naBJZSepUeV;Qi1WRFJoSnU;Swv8DdBhJvC;NnYKpAzraXX;T0kBIwfDa5N;o5kVh4kRFF9;JAX5HOu665U;QkW2vpJn1z5;lhQWQlxrzOv;wiw3Y0Zkjii;uyey4mCGZLz;GPnoGnyocHS;sx7TSP921al;s0mlmmPbCdq;f3fhveMBAt2;cmaAWx5VuEx;aGmAt9Ovc57;LVZ0zsPVm3f;gr4bKti3JEw;cMN7aHkXHhs;BFeLG7TNOvq;A9PF5ZTUGPN;tHivnx60q8q;wdPJGHpacCb;M5hPC2GC9N8;bMxzvvXKsGH;Ofuxl3WRHb0;QMSuZWQIf8a;QJ6ujwA2gko;jgNrV7s1AiP;MT5wClwhTPx;ALvAHqLDm9c;HnYt4ZXti24;QiNO2NlJJNc;SGZoMo3Hx4j;Qc94kxm2YJe;i6RTvjFSehw;PP68mDkB94t;sDQlOpLyZiR;u0Akq9GFioM;dzwW7D68fMo;wNTH1o9J9QV;xdxcfEcIPIP;QcyVv7YjiZs;vr8IFPHqD2w;HfQiHEQTJ0g;hmpaTGAqd0z;D7RcnVq5INU;QAfFgIPHa3s;eXYjyu0ey8I;QuufqC3FcDL;TwYb8CZJtCz;t1ErzIjc6Rq;veCj7xnZiZf&dimension=ou:qwzcYsSzL7k;LEVEL-5&dimension=pe:LAST_MONTH&displayProperty=NAME&outputIdScheme=NAME%22),%5BDelimiter=%22,", Columns=4, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"En-têtes promus" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Type modifié" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"En-têtes promus",{{"Data", type text}, {"Organisation unit", type text}, {"Period", type text}, {"Value", type text}})
in
#"Type modifié"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"PriorStepNameGoesHere", List.Distinct(Source[Data]), "Data", "value")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.
My goal is to import this data and update it monthly without modifying these queries, but it's powerbi alone that does the job.
Can I expect such a result with this query?
In other words, without making any manual changes, the data will be presented as it currently is. Thanks you !

Comment: Sorry I am unsure what you are asking. If there is a column named Data and one named value then this will work.  If this answer solves your issue please upvote and toggle checkmark to accept as solved

Comment: Yes you understood my question but what I need is automation. That is to say that once the data arrived in power bi is already formatted and it will no longer need manual manipulation.
THANKS !